# unintended alterering of df when copy was made in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy

Let df be my pandas dataframe of the data and dfcopy its copy,

```
data = [[1,['A1']],[3,['A2','A2','A1']], [1,['A2']]]  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
dfcopy = df.copy()  

     0    1  
0    1    ['A1']
1    3    ['A2', 'A2', 'A1']
2    1    ['A2']
```

the id of df is 1874789864000 and the id of dfcopy is 1874789865736. Different as expected. 
Now I want to remove **one** 'A2' at position dfcopy[1,1] and reduce dfcopy[1,0] with **one** (column 0 is the length of the list in column 1)

```
dfcopy.at[1,0]=dfcopy.at[1,0]-1  
df =
     0    1  
0    1    ['A1']
1    3    ['A2', 'A2', 'A1']
2    1    ['A2']
dfcopy =
     0    1  
0    1    ['A1']
1    2    ['A2', 'A2', 'A1']
2    1    ['A2']
```

as I expect, the amount in column 0 is reduced in only dfcopy.
Now I remove 'A2' of the element dfcopy[1,1]

```
dfcopy.at[1,1].remove('A2')
df =
     0    1  
0    1    ['A1']
1    3    [ 'A2', 'A1']
2    1    ['A2']
dfcopy =
     0    1  
0    1    ['A1']
1    2    [ 'A2', 'A1']
2    1    ['A2']
```

The id's are still the same as before (not shown) but now my df is altered in position df[1,1]
**why is this happening while I defined a copy, and how do I fix this?**

```
intended output:  

df =
     0    1  
0    1    ['A1']
1    3    [ 'A2', 'A2', 'A1']
2    1    ['A2']
dfcopy =
     0    1  
0    1    ['A1']
1    2    [ 'A2', 'A1']
2    1    ['A2']
```

I looked a lot on the documentary and here on Stackoverflow but do not understand why this happens.

**WORKAROUND**

```
data = [[1,['A1']],[3,['A2','A2','A1']], [1,['A2']]]  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
dfcopy = df.copy()
dfcopy.at[1,0]=dfcopy.at[1,0]-1 
list = list(dfcopy.at[1,1])
list.remove('A2')
dfcopy.at[1,1] = list

df =
     0    1  
0    1    ['A1']
1    3    [ 'A2', 'A2', 'A1']
2    1    ['A2']
dfcopy =
     0    1  
0    1    ['A1']
1    2    [ 'A2', 'A1']
2    1    ['A2']
```

Comment: It seems as if the "deep" copy of panda dataframes is not that deep...

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy
df=copy.deepcopy(df)
```

might work for you!

As mentioned in the comment,

> .copy()

has default attribute

> deep=True

, but it is not deep as you want it to be

Comment: This does not work, neither does:  dfcopy = copy.deepcopy(copy.deepcopy(copy.deepcopy(df)))

Comment: Did you find an answer to it?

Comment: I did not find an answer for why it happens, but I did manage to construct a workaround. You can see this in my edit in the question.